# reply already submitted in a flutter app. I'm using image_picker and image_editor_plus plugins in my app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm getting this error in my Flutter app. The app is using image_picker v1.0.4 and image_editor_plus v1.0.4 plugins.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2342, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:166571 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.invizio.custom_order/com.invizio.custom_order.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce this error. This was from Crashlytics logs.